# Erro cópia de arquivo em linguagem C

Tags: c, arquivo

Oi! Estou tentando criar uma cópia de um arquivo em C, mas não estou conseguindo copiar o conteúdo, está só criando um novo arquivo em branco, será que alguém pode ver onde estou errando?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[100];
    FILE *file = fopen("/home/ananda/Downloads/pratica12/GAAL.txt", "r");
    if(file == NULL){
        printf("arquivo inexistente\n");
        return 0;
    }

    FILE *file1 = fopen("/home/ananda/Downloads/pratica12/GAAL2.txt", "w");
    if(file == NULL){
        printf("arquivo inexistente\n");
        return 0;


   while (fgets (str, 100, file) != NULL){
       fputs(str, file1);
return 0;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

É tudo uma questão de identar corretamente o código. Pondo os espaços nos lugares devidos o erro fica imediatamente claro:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[100];
    FILE *file = fopen("/home/ananda/Downloads/pratica12/GAAL.txt", "r");
    if(file == NULL){
        printf("arquivo inexistente\n");
        return 0;
    }

    FILE *file1 = fopen("/home/ananda/Downloads/pratica12/GAAL2.txt", "w");
    if(file == NULL){
        printf("arquivo inexistente\n");
        return 0;


        while (fgets (str, 100, file) != NULL){
            fputs(str, file1);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Imagino que esse `while` esteja no lugar errado. Este `return 0;` também não deveria estar dentro do `while`. Arrumando isso o código funciona como deveria.

Comment: Eu acho incrível como este ainda precisa ser o conselho mais dado.

Comment: Muita gente que ta começando considera que identar é frescura. **Não é.**